# SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, header, ssrs-expression

I have to create a report and the header is not query based so I created the header like = `"Name of the company" & vbcrlf & "name of the report"` so on now my question is how do I make Name of the company Bold and Report name bold too?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have set the above as an expression (it appears in design view like "Expr") then you can select the expression, choose placeholder properties, then set the font format to the desired appearance

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, It will definitely work.

Use following expression

```
="<b>" + Fields!NameOfTheCompany.Value + "</b>" + vbcrlf + "<b>" + Fields!ReportName.Value + "</b>"
```

Comment: Like this but(!) select the expression, choose placeholder properties, choose the HTML option.

Comment: that is also one option. but what if user only wants to use bold for particular text. that's why I've suggested this one.

Comment: Wel, enabling HTML makes that possible. You can use all kind of HTML tags to format your text. As far as I know the use of HTML is standard disabled in textboxes. What I wrote is an addition to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First highlight your expression.

[image]

then you have two options:

- On the menu bar you could click the 'B' icon
  [image]
  *Or Right click on the highlighted text and select 'Placeholder Properties'. Then on the Placeholder Properties select 'Font' and from there check the  'B' checkbox.

[image]